# Write a recursive function to convert a String into the number it represents. e.g. for input “1231” you should return integer 1231

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class ReturnNumberGivenInAString {

    public static int number(String s1,int p)
    {
        if(s1.length()==0)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        for(int i = 0; i<=9;i++)
        {
            if(s1.charAt(0)==i)
            {
                p = p + i*10;
            }

        }
        int s = number(s1.substring(1), p);

        return s;


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s1 = s.next();
        int p = 0;
        System.out.println(number(s1,p));



    }

}
```

it is showing 0 as the output
while debugging i noticed that s1.charAt(0) is not getting compared to i
please tell me the mistake in my code

Answer (score 1):

Here is the problem:

```
    if(s1.charAt(0)==i)
```

As you are doing the integer comparison so `s1.charAt(0)` returned value will be converted to its ascii equivalent.

To fix this you may do something like this:

```
    if(Character.getNumericValue(s1.charAt(0))==i)
```

Answer (score 0):

s1.chatAt(0) will return a character, which you're comparing with int.You need to convert that char to int first before comparing.

Use `Character.getNumericValue(s1.charAt(0))`